# Fill remaining width of parent div (non-flexbox or calc)

Tags: css

```css
.alert {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 70px;
  min-width: 400px;
}
.alert-forgotPassword {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.alert-forgotPassword-input-wrapper {
  float: left;
}
.alert-forgotPassword-input {
  width: 100%;
}
.alert-forgotPassword-button-wrapper {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <div>
    <div class="alert-forgotPassword-input-wrapper">
      <input class="alert-forgotPassword-input" type="text" size="" placeholder="your.email@company.com">
    </div>
    <div class="alert-forgotPassword-button-wrapper">
      <button>Reset Password</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://codepen.io/basickarl/pen/WwjEqy

The above code gets the divs beside each other. I would like for the input box to be 100% in width so that it's always touching the side of the button for example below.

Example if parent div is stretched wider:

[image]

Example if parent div is smaller in width:

[image]

I wish for a pure css/html solution that works with ie9 and up, changes to the structure is welcome! Less is welcome however.

Comment: Your title is confusing. If the input were 100% width it would stretch over/under the button. You seem to want it to take up all *remaining* width, right?

Comment: @Jeroen Indeed! I apologize for the title, what should I rename it as?

Comment: Also, it would help if you elaborate a bit. Tell us what you've tried and researched. Tell us whether you're allowed to change the html structure or whether it's generated by a framework. Tell us what browsers you need to support. Etc. etc.

Comment: @Jeroen No frameworks are allowed, pure css and html! I'll add the info.

Comment: Is flexbox an option?

Comment: @j08691 I'm afraid not, otherwise I'd have this solved :)

Comment: Is calc an option?

Comment: @miro Updated my question, pure css only! Pain in the ass I know, but no external libraries are allowed :(

Comment: `calc()` doesn't require any libs.

Comment: @j08691 Nor does `flex-box`. It's all pure CSS3.

Comment: What do you mean by a pure CSS solution? Both calc() and flexbox *are* CSS and don't require any libraries. Do you really mean CSS2?

Comment: I would just use `display: flex` and let it degrade in browsers that dont support it. flexbox is supported by IE 10+ so not many users would be affected.

Comment: @j08691 You have taught me something new today! Well actually I should of put that it is ie9 that it has to work with. Doh my fault.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use flexbox, you can do it like this with your current HTML content :

**CSS**

```
.alert-forgotPassword {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.alert-forgotPassword-input-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  padding-top: 1px;
}
.alert-forgotPassword-input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.alert-forgotPassword-button-wrapper {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Instead of `float: right` on your input wrapper, you can use `overflow: auto` so that the block will take as many space horizontally as it can. So its width will fit the space between the left side of the parent and the button wrapper, no matter the width of the parent block.

The left padding on the button wrapper allows to introduce a space between the button and the input. It would work as well with a right padding on the input wrapper, or a margin on any of the wrappers. It's just a personnal preference.

I added a top padding of 1px on the input wrapper just to align vertically input and button.

The `box-sizing: border-box` on the input is necessary because your input has a border. Without it, with a width of 100%, your input would actually be larger than 100% : its width would be 100% of the container + the width of the border. And in this case, `overflow: auto` would make an horizontal scroll-bar appear (because the content would be larger than the container). And we don't want an ugly scroll-bar !

### [See Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxWGbz)

Comment: I remember the day I discover the `overflow: auto` : it was like Christmas :-D

Comment: much better answer now that it has an explaination! +1

Answer (score 1):

Here it is accomplished with some simplified markup using `display:flex`.

```css
.alert {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 20px;
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 70px;
  min-width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.alert > input {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
.alert > button {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <input type="text" placeholder="your.email@company.com">
  <button>Reset Password</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, either I missed it in the title, or the title was edited after I posted a solution.

Comment: Apologize for the late edit, I'll +1 you anyway as this does work with flex, might help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

You could add changes to width for the wrappers. Text box is 70% and button as 30%.

```
.alert-forgotPassword-input-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

.alert-forgotPassword-button-wrapper {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Hehe sneaky sneaky! Button however has a set width, otherwise this would of worked great!